# Angular UI Date Picker : Not Able to Create it as a week picker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

Here, I am trying to use `angular-ui-datepicker` as a Week Picker.
But I m only getting normal date picker, month picker or year picker i want to create this date picker as week picker.

Here is the `html` code:

```
<input id="datepicker_update" class="form-control" type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{table.format}}"
      ng-model="table.price_list.date_update" ng-value="table.price_list.date_update"
      is-open="table.dt_picker[0]" min-date="dpick.minDate" max-date="'2019-12-22'" 
      datepicker-options="table.dateOptions" date-disabled="table.disabled(date, mode)"
      close-text="Close" placeholder="Update Date" name="date_update" datepicker-mode="'week'" required=""/>
```

And Here is part of: datepicker-options, In `JS` as

```
  vm.dateOptions = {
       formatYear: 'yyyy',
       startingDay: 1,
       minMode: 'week'
  };
```

Comment: `But i m not able to configure this` is very ambiguous, can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the very good example for selecting week in `datepicker` (`angular-ui-datepicker`)

Se this example and try to Use this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/rV6m1c8ovXONtHJjtp2Z?p=preview

Or you can try this also :

http://plnkr.co/edit/YU4gPG?p=preview

Comment: Thanks For Reply..i'll try this :)